# tween.js oncomplete firing early

Tags: tween

I am seeing that oncomplete event fires before the actually tweening is completed.
From github I got the latest version of tween.js
The github URL I used is
https://github.com/sole/tween.js
and currently the latest version is 12
Has anyone seen any similar behavior?

Comment: could you post a simple example here or jsFiddle ?

Comment: hi Vincet,
Did some more debugging and the problem is not with the library but its with my code.
This is what I am trying to do.
I have a group of spheres that I tween from a random position to their position,
Once the tweening is complete I want to place a canvas label on top of them.
The problem with my lable placement code (when I posted the code) was that it fired on the oncomplete of all tweens.
Since that included the first tween that completed my labels wered placed on top of the spheres before they were in their final position.

Comment: So I wrote a condition to call the oncomplete (label placement) only for the last tween set.
But looks like the last tween set is not necessarily the last tween completed.
The results are a lot better then my first iteration where are the labels were out of place.
Now I only see a few labels out of place.
How can I? :)
1) How do I know when all tweens are completed not one Object
2) If I had multiple groups of tweens how can I detect the completion of all tweens within that group.
Sorry I dont have a jsfidel at this point since my code is depended on some serverside calls and is a spaghetti.

Comment: Even if it's not working, can you paste your `new Tween()` code, with the `onComplete` function ?

Comment: Same need as described in the comments (tweeting multiple objects in a loop then, needing a callback to fire ONLY when the tween of the LAST OBJECT finishes). oncomplete triggers for each objects, even with conditions inside the oncomplete block. 100% sure it is weird stuff.